# Is it possible to use `str` to convert the output of a mapping object to a string?

Tags: python

To apply a function to every element of a list, and collect the results back into a list, you might use the following code:

```
output = list(map(function, iterable))
```

However, it does not appear to be possible to do a similar thing with strings.

```
output_str = str(map(function, 'input string'))
```

The above code appears to convert a mapping object to its string representation, rather than performing the iteration process and collecting the results into a `str` type.

As a workaround, an empty string can be joined.

```
output_str = ''.join(map(function, 'input string'))
```

This is a bit strange, because other datatypes use their name as a function call to collect together objects yielded from an iterable.

For example `list(iterable)` can be used to create a `list` type of object from an `iterable`.

Is there a way to get `str` to work similarly to `list` or `dict` when taking the result of a map function call?

Clarification:

A *possible* but not necessarily *good* solution:

```
def to_str(iterable):
    return ''.join(iterable)
```

Comment: `''.join` is the standard way of concatenating multiple strings into one. The empty string is the separator, which here means "no separator".

Comment: You have an iterable of strings, which you want to join. `''.join` is the pythonic way to do that. It has been discussed ad nauseum how intuitive this is, but that’s what it is.

Comment: I do not understand. `str to work similarly to list or dict when taking the result of a map function call?` No, str works with generators like with generators, and with list or dict like with list or dict. A generator is not a list and is not a dict. I do not understand the requirement. `because other datatypes use their name as a function call` I do not understand. Other datatypes are datatypes. Map is a function that outputs a generator. A `str` of a generator is the str of a generator, not of some unrelated datatype. What result do you expect from `str(map(exit, [1]))`?

Comment: `str` produces a _string representation_ of the given argument. It's not obvious that the string representation of an iterable should be all its elements concatenated together. Then `str(['foo', 'bar'])` should also produce `foobar`. Is _that_ expected?

Comment: *"`list(iterable)` can be used to create a `list` type of object from an `iterable`."* — And `str(iterable)` creates a string objects from an iterable. But it's up to the iterable itself how it wants to present itself as a string. `str` has no generic way to represent any and all values "correctly" as strings. It just calls `__str__`/`__repr__`. But that does not cause the generator to unroll itself nor concatenate its elements.

Comment: This is really not a complicated question

Comment: The linked question has absolutly nothing to do with what I am asking here

Comment: Why can't you understand? It's literally so simple. `map()` returns an object which is a lazy evaluated and iteratable thing. Calling `str()` causes the `__str__` or `__repr__` function of the lazy evaluated mapping object to be called. It should be totally obvious this is not what I am asking for. Instead, I am asking for a way to construct a `str` using a syntax like `str(iterable)`. If you do not know a solution for this, then simply don't comment on the question.

Comment: And I explained what `str()` does, which answers why it won’t work. And Python’s mantra is *”there should be one way to do it”*, and the duplicate explains why that one way is `str.join`.

Comment: @deceze It will work, exactly how they want, if they do `str = ''.join` :-)

Comment: @nocomment A *possible* but not necessarily *good* solution… :-)

Comment: @deceze But my version is better, has the desired name and doesn't have the wasteful extra function call and attribute lookup. And it's less code.

Comment: @nocomment Sure. But now `str` does something else in the rest of your code, so there’s that…